# Is it necessary to add permissions in an android app?

Tags: android

Is it necessary to add permissions in an android app ? And if yes, then why ? And if we don't put, then what will happen ?

Are the permissions added only to show them while installing the APK file ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use Google to find a tutorial on the subject.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding permissions  is a required part of the source code for an Android app.
`You can protect your privacy, security, and cell phone bill by paying attention to Android app permissions` when installing those apps – although many users don’t.

A basic Android application has no permissions associated with it by default, meaning it cannot do anything that would adversely impact the user experience or any data on the device, 
So `if we dont declare permission then there will be a restrictions on the specific operations that a particular process can perform.`

If your app lists normal permissions in its manifest (that is, permissions that don't pose much risk to the user's privacy or the device's operation), the system automatically grants those permissions. If your app lists dangerous permissions in its manifest (that is, permissions that could potentially affect the user's privacy or the device's normal operation), the system asks the user to explicitly grant those permissions. The way Android makes the requests depends on the system version, and the system version targeted by your app

for more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Permissions will notify the person downloading the app.

The notification that on some apps you have to accept things like app uses camera/acces to internet etc.

i would suggest adding no more permissions than you realy need if you plan on publishing the app. just to not scare users away by all the permissions you need.

Yes its nessecary on most apps.
It is nessecary to protect the privacy of users.
if you dont put the right permissions in the app wont work.

Answer (score 0):

As you develop your app, you should note when your app is using capabilities that require a permission. Typically, an app is going to need permissions whenever it uses information or resources that the app doesn't create, or performs actions that affect the behavior of the device or other apps. For example, if an app needs to access the internet, use the device camera, or turn Wi-Fi on or off, the app needs the appropriate permission. For a list of system permissions, see [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).